# metafunction to determinate the biggest of all supplied types

Tags: c++, c++11

Can the metafunction below be implemented more elegantly, with less code? What I have now is not very elegant or smartly written.

```
#include <type_traits>

namespace detail
{

template <typename T, typename A, typename ...B>
struct max_type
{
  typedef typename max_type<
    typename std::conditional<(sizeof(A) > sizeof(T)), A, T>::type,
    B...
  >::type type;
};

template <typename T, typename A>
struct max_type<T, A>
{
  typedef typename std::conditional<(sizeof(A) > sizeof(T)), A, T>::type type;
};

}

template <typename A, typename... B>
struct max_type
{
  typedef typename detail::max_type<A, A, B...>::type type;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this? It’s not all that much shorter, but IMHO quite a bit simpler:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename A, typename... B>
struct max_type
{
    typedef typename max_type<A, typename max_type<B...>::type>::type type;
};

template <typename A>
struct max_type<A>
{
    typedef A type;
};

template <typename A, typename B>
struct max_type<A,B>
{
    typedef typename std::conditional<(sizeof(A) > sizeof(B)), A, B>::type type;
};
```

Comment: Nice, even though I've really wanted a bit less code :)